# Signing a C++ executable in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, signing

Is there a way to automatically sign a C++ executable generated by Visual Studio 2008? I couldn't find anything similar to the "signing" tab in Properties that exists for managed apps.

Any ideas? I want to automatically sign my executable when it's built (using msbuild command line).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use signtool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28VS.80%29.aspx) in a post-build step

Comment: how to create this post-build step? What is the syntax?

Comment: I found out by myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386726/how-to-sign-the-output-executable-during-the-build-process-in-visual-studio/4386989#4386989