# How to sign the output executable during the build process in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, code-signing

When I use a `strong name key file` as indicated in the project properties, it requires that all referenced assemblies to also use such a similar signature.

But what I want is to sign using the WinDDK `Signtool.exe`. This I already do manually, but I also want to debug sign assemblies, and the best way of doing that is including the signature in the build, probably as a `AfterBuild` step.

The problem is I don't know how to create a `AfterBuild` step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the following lines to the `*.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Exec Command="sign.bat" />
</Target>
```

And then I added a `sign.bat` file to the project root folder

I found this solution at [some blog](http://www.danielfortunov.com/software/%24daniel_fortunovs_adventures_in_software_development/2009/05/21/invoking_batch_files_from_msbuild)

Comment: broken link broken link

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing things up here.  A strong name is *not* the same thing as the certificate that's added to a binary with signtool.exe.  There is also no requirement that dependent assemblies have a certificate or that it needs to match.  Nor does it make sense to sign a debug build, only your customer is interested in it.  You already know that you can trust yourself.

Running sn.exe to give an assembly a strong name is already supported by msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

In **Properties** of your project >> **Build Events** >> **Post-build event command line**

```
if $(Configuration) == Release C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Windows Kits"\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a $(TargetPath)
```

The `if` condition only signs the **Release** if needed.